# save a dynamically created <textarea> tag using javascript ONLY

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I am creating textarea tags as the user clicks a button. And i want the dynamically created texarea tags to remain as such when we close and open the browser again.

I am able to save the **CONTENT** of the textarea tag,but there is no point in it when the textarea tag itself doesnt remain after closing the browser.

ok: SO here is the code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<button id="A" onclick="add()" type="button">ADD</button>
<button id="S" onclick="save()" type="button">SAVE</button>
<button id="E" onclick="edit()" type="button">EDIT</button>
<button id="D" onclick="del('x')" type="button">DELETE</button>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text_new,x;
var i=0,j,y;
function add()
{
    text_new=document.createElement("textarea");/*I WANT TO STORE THESE CREATED TAGS USING LOCAL STORAGE*/
    text_new.id="a"+i.toString();
    var t = document.createTextNode("");
    text_new.appendChild(t);
    console.log(text_new.id);
    i++;
    document.body.appendChild(text_new);

}

document.body.addEventListener("click", activate);
   function activate()
   {

if(document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() ==="textarea")
    {

     x = document.activeElement.id;
     y=x;
    console.log(x);
    console.log(typeof x);
    }

    }

function save()
{
document.getElementById(x).readOnly=true;
console.log(document.getElementById(x).value);
localStorage.y=document.getElementById(x).value;
document.getElementById(x).value=localStorage.y;
}
function edit()
{
    document.getElementById(x).readOnly=false;
}
function del()
{
   var element = document.getElementById(x);
element.remove();
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried? What code did you use?

Comment: Have you tried cookies?

Comment: I dont know the syntax of saving a tag using localstorage.

Comment: I havent tried cookies, neither do i know how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).
Cookies are data, stored in small text files, on your computer.

- When a user visits a web page, his name can be stored in a cookie.
- Next time the user visits the page, the cookie "remembers" his name.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use html5 web storage, specifically the localStorage.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

I hope this Helps!

Comment: I want to save the entire tag,not just its content,so that the dynamically created tag remains.Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it....

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{

    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-image: url(images/note2.jpg);

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
    button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  background:   black;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;

  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
font-family: Oswald, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.8;
  appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;


  border : 6px solid black;
}
#D:hover
{
    background: red;
}
#S:hover
{
    background: green;
}
 button:hover
 {
  background-color: #417cb8
}

 button:active
 {
  background-color: #417cb8;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #27496d;
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
textarea
{
    height: 170px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-radius: 20px;
    resize: none;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px; 
    padding: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-overflow: auto;

}
#header
{

    height: 100px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;

}

#buts
{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#con
{
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
img
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 60%;
}

</style>
<body>
<div id="header">NOTE IT OR FORGET IT!
<img src="images/note1.png"> </div>
<div id="con">
<div id="buts">
<button id="A" onclick="add()" type="button">ADD</button>
<button id="S" onclick="save()" type="button">SAVE</button>
<button id="E" onclick="edit()" type="button">EDIT</button>
<button id="D" onclick="del('x')" type="button">DELETE</button>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var text_new,x;
var i=0,j,y,num=0;

window.onload=function ()
{i=0;
    for (var key in localStorage)
    {
        text_new=document.createElement("textarea");

        var t = document.createTextNode(localStorage.getItem(key));

          text_new.appendChild(t);
          document.body.appendChild(text_new);
          text_new.id=key;
          i++;

    } 
}
/*window.onbeforeunload=function()
{
    var x=document.querySelectorAll("textarea");

    for(num=0;num<x.length;x++)
    {
        if
    }
}   

}*/
function add()
{
    text_new=document.createElement("textarea");
    text_new.id="a"+i.toString();
    for(var key in localStorage)
    {
        if (text_new.id==key)
        {
            i++;
            text_new.id="a"+i.toString();
        }
    }
    var t = document.createTextNode("");
    text_new.appendChild(t);
    console.log(text_new.id);
    i++;
    document.body.appendChild(text_new);

}

document.body.addEventListener("click", activate);
   function activate()
   {

if(document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() ==="textarea")
    {

     x = document.activeElement.id;
     console.log(x);

    }

    }

function save()
{
    if((document.getElementById(x).readOnly==false)&&(document.getElementById(x).value!=""))
    {

document.getElementById(x).readOnly=true;
console.log(x);

console.log(document.getElementById(x).value);
localStorage.setItem(x,document.getElementById(x).value);
document.getElementById(x).value=localStorage.getItem(x);
}

}
function edit()
{
    document.getElementById(x).readOnly=false;
}
function del()
{
   var element = document.getElementById(x);
   localStorage.removeItem(x);
element.remove();
}


</script>

</html>
```